# Action method parameter is not null although it should be

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this entry in the routing table:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
                "instructions/new",
                 new { controller = "Instructions", action = "NewInstructions" },
                 new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
               );
```

this method

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult NewInstructions(Client client)
 {
     var instructions = instructionService.Create(client);
     return RedirectToAction("Instructions", new { id = instructions.Id });
 }
```

and this link to the method

```
<a href="/instructions/new">create a new one</a>
```

In this case, the `client` parameter is not null when the action method is invoked. Instead, it is apparently created by calling the `Client`'s parameterless constructor.

However, when I make the same action method accessible via POST, the `client` parameter is correctly set to `null`.

Is this a standard behavior of the `DefaultModelBinder` in cases when the value for a parameter is not provided by the request to distinguish between GET and POST and behave differently for each one of them?

Comment: Hi @twoflower, did you find a way to change this behaviour?  I've ran into the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. I still don't know the reason.

Comment: Argh, I was worried you might say that.  I'll let you know if I figure out what's going on! :-)  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Sure, if you find something out, post the response here :)

Answer (score 0):

How your site is transferred to the action "NewInstructions" ? 
if you come from action return View("NewInstructions") then it may carry parameter value from previous post.

However, if you use return RedirectToAction(...) then parameters should be as set, or null if optional.

Comment: No, I don't post the property in the request. For POST request, it behaves correctly. For a GET request, however, the parameter is non-null and I don't know why. `Request.Form` collection is empty.

Comment: The `Client` object IS NOT null when I enter the `NewInstructions` action through the link above (i.e. a GET request).

Comment: Problem is that the value for that parameter is not specified anywhere by the request so I would expect it to take its default value, which is `null`. I can't see how it could come from a cache - I do not use the cache myself.

Comment: I don't want to remove it. Somewhere else I may need to actually supply the value for that parameter.

Comment: OK, then make it an optional parameter.  public ActionResult NewInstructions(Client client = null)

Comment: That doesn't help, the parameter still isn't `null` in the action method.

Comment: How your site is transferred to the action "NewInstructions" ? if you come from action return View("NewInstructions") then it may carry parameter value from previous post. However, if you use return RedirectToAction(...) then parameters should be as set, or null if optional.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12596/discussion-between-elyusubov-and-twoflower)